# AccountKit SDK was not initialized?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I have a problem with the AccountKit JavaScript SDK ,
When i integrate it with my website it works fine with Firefox but in Chrome it works fine first, but when i try to use it again it gives me this error:

```
'AccountKit SDK was not initialized. Call AccountKit.init first.'
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to add the initialization immediately after the sdk loads. Seems like when there is much data/code to load before the initialization, it sometimes hangs.
ie

```
<script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
      AccountKit.init(
              {
                appId:youID,
                state:"{{csrf}}",
                version:"v1.1"
              }
            );
             console.log("{{csrf}}")

          };

    </script>
```

NOT

```
<script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>

//   some code

<script type="text/javascript">
  AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
  AccountKit.init(
          {
            appId:youID,
            state:"{{csrf}}",
            version:"v1.1"
          }
        );
         console.log("{{csrf}}")

      };

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue and I solve it. Just call your AccountKit.init your main file(index.html) where your app hold all scripts. From me it looks like this:
**index.html**

```
<script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
      AccountKit.init(
              {
                appId:youID,
                state:"{{csrf}}",
                version:"v1.1"
              }
            );
             console.log("{{csrf}}")

          };

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add in the code that you're using?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/web

You do need to call AccountKit.init as part of the setup.